# Array of pointer chrash on function

Tags: c++

I have an array of pointers that all will have some value and and a function. When the function runs it seems like it can't find the values.

The code that crash the program is almost at the bottom.

The .h file for my class:

```
#ifndef DICE_H
#define DICE_H
class Dice
{
    public:
        int value;
        int nrOfFaces;
        Dice();
        void toss();
};
#endif
```

And my .cpp file for my class:

```
#include "Dice.h"
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

Dice::Dice()
{
    nrOfFaces = 6;
    value = 0;
}
//this function gives the dice a new random value
void Dice::toss()
{
    value = rand() % nrOfFaces + 1;
}
```

main() function:

```
int main(){
    srand(static_cast<unsigned>(time(NULL)));

    Playboard* board = new Playboard();
    Dice** dice = new Dice*[5];
    int round = 0;

    while (1){
        system("CLS");
        board->PrintBoard();

        cout << endl;

        cout << endl << "Press Enter to roll the dices" << endl;
        getchar();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            dice[i]->toss(); //ERROR
            cout << dice[i]->value << AddSpaces(2);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the error output that you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dice[i]` is a pointer type. And you never assign a valid pointer to it.

Change:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        dice[i]->toss(); //ERROR
        cout << dice[i]->value << AddSpaces(2);
    }
```

To:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        dice[i] = new Dice();  // Assign a VALID POINTER to dice[i]
        dice[i]->toss(); //NO ERROR
        cout << dice[i]->value << AddSpaces(2);
    }
```

Comment: I had it like that from beginning but i got this from the one correcting: "You needed to create array of 5 pointers which points to Dice objects what you did is that you create a pointer which points to an array of 5 Dice objects. I hope you know the difference!"

Answer (score 2):

You allocate an array of five pointers, but you don't actually allocate memory for any of those pointers to point to, which leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) when you dereference those (uninitialized) pointers. Remember that the value of uninitialized memory is *indeterminate* (and in reality seemingly random).

In this case there is *no need* to use pointers or dynamic allocation at all, just use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array):

```
std::array<Dice, 5> dice;
```

And use as a normal array:

```
dice[i].toss();
```

Comment: It looks like a class assignment, with specific odd requirements (that weren't mentioned in the question)